# Error al ejecutar el Activity en Aplicación Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Estoy ejecutando una aplicación creada en Xamarin, pero en la linea de:

```
setContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Me marca el siguiente error:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

Este es mi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Creo que el problema está ahí, pero no logro identificarlo, es la primera vez que ocupo fragment.

A qué se refiere el error InflateException??

ACTUALIZADO: Este es mi Main Activity:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
```

y esta es la salida del Output:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

An unhandled exception occured.
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Cambia tu layout , debería quedar así :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, modifiqué mi layout pero ahora me aparece: "Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>"

Comment: Puedes poner el log completo y tambien tu Activity en tu pregunta

Comment: Listo, ya lo puse :)

Comment: Al parecer no has importado la libreria de maps en tu proyecto

Comment: Adjunté una imagen de mis referencias

Comment: Te falta la referencia de maps, revisa bien que necesitas ya que no he usado xamarin

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: Perdón, ese es el error que me sale